jsonb for pgsql not working with laravel but raw query is working with pgsql
$response = \App\Models\BinResponse::query()
        ->selectRaw('id, response')
        ->whereRaw("response::jsonb IS NOT NULL")
        ->get();

    dd($response);

generates following pgsql
select id, response from "bin_responses" where response::jsonb IS NOT NULL

I want to retrieve all valid json from my pgsql, I can do that with the raw query but from laravel eloquent it throws following error
SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR: invalid input syntax for type json DETAIL: The input string ended unexpectedly. CONTEXT: JSON data, line 1:



laravel version 9.0, PHP version 8.1, pgsql 15.2
summary: jsonb is not working with laravel but working with raw query, my column data type is text, is there any way to get valid json with laravel having field type text?

That query will always fail if there is at least one string in the table that is not a valid JSON, because the type conversion takes place before the NULL-ness test.
I recommend that you upgrade to PostgreSQL v16 or better and use the new type validity checking functions:
SELECT id, response
FROM "bin_responses"
WHERE pg_input_is_valid(response, 'jsonb');

In older versions, you could create a function as a workaround:
CREATE FUNCTION is_json(text) RETURNS boolean
   LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE AS
$$BEGIN
   PERFORM CAST($1 AS jsonb);
   RETURN TRUE;
EXCEPTION WHEN invalid_text_representation THEN
   RETURN FALSE;
END;$$;

Note that calling that function starts a subtransaction, so performance will suffer if you call it more than 64 times in a transaction.

thanks a lot for your help, but it is really not possible to update db version in the production, I need the solution in current version
